# Primitive Pythagorean Triple less than or equal to 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the question:

Find all primitive Pythagorean triples (a, b, c) satisfying a + b ≤ 11.

How do I set a system of equations? I know that:

$$a=2st $$
$$ b=s^{2}-t^{2} $$
$$c=s^{2}+t^{2}$$

But no idea how to start.

Comment: $(s^2+t^2)^2\le11^2.$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $a=2st,\ b=s^2-t^2,\ c=s^2+t^2$ provide Pythagorean triples, but unless $s$ and $t$ have different parity, all of $a,b,c$ will be even and the triple will NOT be primitive. If we require $s,t$ to have different parity, one of them is even and $a=2st$ will in fact be divisible by $4$. Hence, the only possible values for $a$ are $4,8$.

You should quickly see that $8$ affords no Pythagorean triples such that $a+b\le 11$. You should know that the primitive Pythagorean triple which contains $4$ is $a=4,b=3,c=5$ and you are done.